# How to use __stdcall functions from Java?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to use some functions nested in a `.dll` from Java. I've tried the basic approaches with JNI and JNA but without any success. I looked inside the `.dll` with Dependency Walker and found out that the functions are not beginning with `Java_com_...` as I was expecting due to Google and JNI Documentation.

Is there a possibility to get access to these functions though?

Also, I could identify the modifiers of the functions. All of them have the modifier `__stdcall`.

I would be thankful to get any hint or idea.

Comment: _"as I was expecting due to Google and JNI Documentation"_ Was this DLL intended to be called from Java code? Otherwise there's no reason to expect it to follow the JNI naming scheme for its functions. One solution would be to write your own DLL which provides a set of JNI functions, and this DLL would in turn link against the the other DLL and call its functions.

Comment: What exactly did you try?  JNA is designed to load and invoke functions from a shared library that follows `C` language compatibility.  If it's not a JNI DLL, then you'd have to write your own JNI code (or use JNA) in order to access its functions.

Comment: thanks. The .dll is not supposed to be called from Java code. The sollution with JNA wasn't successfull either. I guess there is no other option than write an own .dll to get access to the functions. Thanks for your help!!!